# can Jfrog artifactory manage mainframe artifacts

Tags: artifactory, mainframe

Generally mainframe binaries are stored in PDS/file system to manage mainframe artifacts.

Instead Mainframe PDS, can JFrog Artifactory help in managing mainframe artifacts ?

In case there is related article or link or document, please share such that I can go through it.

I am new to JFrog Artifactory and want to know whether it will suit for need and then explore it.

Answer (score 1):

JFrog Artifactory doesn't support Mainframe out of the box, but you can use [Generic repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories) which can store any type of binaries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but indirectly. When used with a modern pipeline, you absolutely can store packages from say IBM Urbancode in Artifactory, pull those out and deploy via Urbancode. UCD is an excellent tool for deployment on z/OS. It is often coupled with Dependency Based Build which handles compilation of source that has been migrated from legacy SCM tools into Git.

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/wasdevops/blogs/laurel-dickson-bull1/2022/07/22/integrating-artifactory-with-ibm-urbancode-deploy